# MVC error "requires ienumerable instead of list"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, ienumerable

Trying to display values from 2 tables, staff and department so i tried to perform a linq sql query but it doesn't work when i open my application in the web browser. New to MVC and this is my first time using linq to sql so I'm not sure whats wrong!

My error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`4[System.String,System.String,StaffDetails.Models.Department,StaffDetails.Models.Site]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[StaffDetails.Models.Staff]'.

Index view

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<Staff> staffList = new List<Staff>();

        var query = (from s in db.Staffs
                     from d in db.Departments
                     where s.DeptID == d.DeptID
                     select new
                     {
                         name = s.Name,
                         email = s.Email,
                         department = s.Department,
                         site = d.Site
                     }
                     ).ToList();

        return View(query);
    }
```

Tables

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are passing an anonymous type but your view expects `IEnumerable<Staff>`, so while projecting your `LINQ` query you need to project `Staff` type like this:-

```
List<Staff> query = (from s in db.Staffs
                     from d in db.Departments
                     where s.DeptID == d.DeptID
                     select new Staff //here
                     {
                         Name = s.Name,
                         Email= s.Email,
                         Department = s.Department,
                         Site = d.Site
                     }).ToList();
```

**Update:**

Okay so your `Staff` is a mapped entity so in that case you should not be able to map it directly. You either need a `DTO` or alternatively you can first project the anonymous type and bring the operation in linq-to-objects using `AsEnumerable()` and then project from there like this:-

```
IEnumerable<Staff> staffList = (from s in db.Staffs
                     from d in db.Departments
                     where s.DeptID == d.DeptID
                     select new
                     {
                         name = s.Name,
                         email = s.Email,
                         department = s.Department,
                         site = d.Site
                     }).AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(x => new new Staff 
                          {
                             Name = x.name,
                             Email= x.email,
                             Department = x.department,
                             Site = x.site
                          });
```

Comment: hello! After implementing that I got another error "The entity or complex type 'StaffDBModel.Staff' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." Do you know why I got the error? Thank you for your help! :>

Comment: @eyeballs - You're welcome. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work